# Ajax.BeginForm call JS function OnBegin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi regarding https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/function-declarations.html I define my JS function like this

```
<script language="javascript">
    var clearMessage = function ClearMessage() {
        $("#result").html("");
    };
</script>
```

And I try to call it in OnBegin method from MVC ajax,

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post", OnBegin = "ClearMessage" }))
```

But I getting error that function not exit,
how to call my function that described by this best practice ? (without *var clearMessage* evering working correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never seen such syntax. Don't even know if it is valid javascript.

Try defining your function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClearMessage = function() {
        $("#result").html("");
    };
</script>
```

or like this (which is pretty much the same):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClearMessage() {
        $("#result").html("");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: by artical point of view last example is antipattern. Is it true ?

Comment: No, it is not anti-pattern. You still have lots of code that is using it. It is just that the first example is preferred because it allows you to define the scope of the `ClearMessage` function in a more granular level. Whereas with the second example the function is defined in the window global scope.